# Optimize X3DOM Animation using Interpolators

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I want to visualize a cross belt Sorter with x3dom. The cross belt sorter has a form of a loop with 90° degree arcs. For the cross belts I use:

< Rectangle2D size='0.6 0.6'/>

The Sorter has 58 cross belts and for each cross belt, I want dynamically change the color of the material via javascript. The cross belts should move along the sorter as in real. Therefore I use the tag:

< timeSensor DEF='timeKOSorter' cycleInterval='60' loop='true'>< /timeSensor>

and for example for the cross belt 0:

< PositionInterpolator DEF='POSKO01_0' key='0 0.344 0.355 0.366 0.377 0.389 0.4 0.411 0.433 0.444 0.455 0.466 0.478 0.489 0.5 0.844 0.855 0.866 0.877 0.889 0.9 0.911 0.933 0.944 0.955 0.966 0.978 0.989 1.0 ' keyValue='8.0 0 0.0  -8.0 0 0.0  -8.518 0 0.068  -9.0 0 0.268  -9.414 0 0.586  -9.732 0 1.0  -9.932 0 1.482  -10.0 0 2.0  -10.0 0 3.0  -9.932 0 3.518  -9.732 0 4.0  -9.414 0 4.414  -9.0 0 4.732  -8.518 0 4.932  -8.0 0 5.0  8.0 0 5.0  8.518 0 4.932  9.0 0 4.732  9.414 0 4.414  9.732 0 4.0  9.932 0 3.518  10.0 0 3.0  10.0 0 2.0  9.932 0 1.482  9.732 0 1.0  9.414 0 0.586  9.0 0 0.268  8.518 0 0.068  8.0 0 0.0  '>< /PositionInterpolator>
< Route fromNode='timeKOSorter' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='POSKO01_0' toField='set_fraction'>< /Route>
< Route fromNode='POSKO01_0' fromField ='value_changed' toNode='crossKO01_0' toField='translation'>< /Route>
< OrientationInterpolator DEF='oriKOSorterKO01_0' key='0 0.344 0.355 0.366 0.377 0.389 0.4 0.411 0.433 0.444 0.455 0.466 0.478 0.489 0.5 0.844 0.855 0.866 0.877 0.889 0.9 0.911 0.933 0.944 0.955 0.966 0.978 0.989 1.0 ' keyValue='0 1 0 0.0  0 1 0 0.0  0 1 0 0.262  0 1 0 0.524  0 1 0 0.785  0 1 0 1.047  0 1 0 1.309  0 1 0 1.571  0 1 0 1.571  0 1 0 1.833  0 1 0 2.094  0 1 0 2.356  0 1 0 2.618  0 1 0 2.88  0 1 0 3.142  0 1 0 3.142  0 1 0 3.403  0 1 0 3.665  0 1 0 3.927  0 1 0 4.189  0 1 0 4.451  0 1 0 4.712  0 1 0 4.712  0 1 0 4.974  0 1 0 5.236  0 1 0 5.498  0 1 0 5.76  0 1 0 6.021  0 1 0 0.0  '>< /OrientationInterpolator>
< Route fromNode='timeKOSorter' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='oriKOSorterKO01_0' toField='set_fraction'>< /Route>
< Route fromNode='oriKOSorterKO01_0' fromField ='value_changed' toNode='crossKO01_0' toField='rotation'>< /Route>

My problem now is, that if I animate 2 Sorters with each 58 cross belts it costs a lot of CPU time. On my computer it uses more than 40 % CPU power. Have anyone an idea how to achieve a better performance?

Answer (score 0):

If the 58 objects could all move in the same direction, you could just put them all under one transform and make an interpolator for that transform.

If not, maybe try:

http://doc.x3dom.org/author/runtime.html#enterFrame

and change the translation/rotation of the objects via dom manipulation in that function.